# Test your app for Windows 10 S

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge

I tried to test my application in the Production mode policy with self-signed apps. I used SignTool to sign my application with the test certificate from Appx Test Root Agency Folder which was successful, but when i tried to run the  application it said "This certificate is not valid because one of the certification authorities in the certificate path does not appear to be allowed to issue certificate or this certificate cannot be used as an end-entity certificate."  What can be the problem?
[Here is  the link to documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-test-windows-s)

Comment: Have you installed the certificate on your machine?

Comment: Hi Stefan, Yes I did install. then I tried to run my Desktop Bridge application it said opening the package from location failed. and the Certificate information was:"This certificate is not valid because one of the certification authorities in the certificate path does not appear to be allowed to issue the certificate or this certificate cannot be used as an end-entity certificate." maybe I am doing something wrong, but I only followed the guidelines from the website.

Comment: I have reached out to the owners of this guidance and will follow up here as soon as I hear back.

Comment: Seems like we are missing a detail in the guidance. The publisher of the app needs to match the cert, so you will need to temporarily update the appxmanifest to use "CN=Appx Test Root Agency" as the Publisher, so it matches the cert. Please let me know if this doesn't help.

Comment: Also here is a more detailed, step-by-step description: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2017/06/15/porting-and-testing-your-classic-desktop-applications-on-windows-10-s-with-the-desktop-bridge/

Comment: Stefan, thank you.I knew that I had to change the name of the publisher, but  I see that there is a new certificate, and now everything is working. Thank you so much

Comment: Glad to hear it's working now. I will post this as answer. Please close it out by marking as answer so we can get it off the unanswered list of questions.

Answer (score 2):

The certificate has been updated recently. If you download now it should work. Also here is a [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2017/06/15/porting-and-testing-your-classic-desktop-applications-on-windows-10-s-with-the-desktop-bridge/) to a more detailed step-by-step guidance for the testing procedure.

Comment: The link no longer works. Is it same as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-test-windows-s?